# Morans correlogram with only one point. What is wrong?

Tags: r

Im trying Moran's I and respective plot in r. But the plot has only one point. I have no idea of what is going wrong. The code is based on<
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/9688_a49c681fab974bbca889e3eae9fbb837.html>

## my data called "coordenata"

```
   resid         x         y
1   0.07785411 -53.20342 -22.66700
2  -0.28358702 -53.20389 -22.66864
3  -0.64011338 -53.21392 -22.68122
4   1.22071249 -53.21311 -22.72369
5   0.95734778 -53.28469 -22.75289
6   0.35345302 -53.25822 -22.74850
7  -0.68357738 -53.28344 -22.70694
8  -1.24596010 -53.32950 -22.72872
9  -0.19944162 -53.33669 -22.73561
10  0.67544909 -53.36756 -22.80767
11  0.64002961 -53.35947 -22.79958
12  0.04564233 -53.21889 -22.67419
13  0.01618436 -53.24522 -22.70144
14 -2.65436794 -53.23017 -22.69292
15  0.72096256 -53.25539 -22.69978
16  0.89656515 -53.28489 -22.72222
17  1.85358579 -53.33069 -22.79161
18 -0.03590077 -53.33200 -22.78336
19  0.32348975 -53.33494 -22.78586
20  2.06771402 -53.37781 -22.77869
21 -1.02190709 -53.30492 -22.77244
22 -2.02813250 -53.53917 -22.79856
23 -1.20702445 -53.53858 -22.79406
24 -1.24091732 -53.55272 -22.80536
25 -1.13491596 -53.56181 -22.82914
26 -0.82934613 -53.56422 -22.83417
27  1.23418758 -53.60017 -22.85531
28 -1.72808514 -53.65900 -22.97828
29 -0.02144049 -53.65908 -22.97497
30  0.49174568 -53.64597 -22.95439
31 -0.54408149 -53.64217 -22.91033
32 -0.37111342 -53.61447 -22.86269
33 -0.31121931 -53.27153 -22.70036
34  0.32419211 -53.30308 -22.72183
35  1.57980287 -53.33053 -22.72947
36 -1.91156060 -53.34633 -22.74722
37 -0.79036645 -53.23667 -22.68925
```

## the code

```
coordinates(coordenata)<-c("x","y")

fit2<-correlog(coordenata$x,coordenata$y,coordenata$resid,increment=5,resamp=100,quiet=T)

plot(fit2)
```

[image: plot with only one point]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Those are probably latitude and longitude coordinates (somewhere in Brazil?). So use `latlon = TRUE` in the function call.

Comment: Yeah its Brazil. It works! Tanks @AndyW!